# How to track variables in VSCode's debugger on a python GUI (Tkinter) app?

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode-debugger

I can't make the VSCode's debbuger to keep track of my variables when i use it with any GUI(tkinter or kivy). When i start the program the breakpoints works as expected. The variables are showing on the left panel and everyting works fine, i can even add them to the "watch" group. At this point, the window didn't opened yet. After i run all the breakpoints, the window opens but all of my variables on the left panel simply disapear, even the "watch" ones are set to "not available". The same issue happens when i try to track variables on a thread function, so i wonder if this is related? I've even tried to include "subProcess": true" on my launch.json but it didn't helped at all.

I made the following example just to show what i mean. In the code i'd like to keep track of "test" at all times, but after the window opens i can't track it anymore. I know the code is working because it prints the value when the function is called! Another thing i've noticed is that **if some exception is raised, all the variables on the panel start to show** and the window is frozen. I must be doing something the wrong way, but i'd really appreciate any help since changing variable values in real time would help so much.
[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

test = 0

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        test = value
        print(test)
        meters.set(int(0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Meters")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = StringVar()
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

meters = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calculate)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you see when you pause execution? and why not just put a breakpoint in `calculate`?

Comment: @starball ty for the reply!
When i press the pause button actually nothing happens, kinda strange! 

As for the breakpoint, the window opens but nothing happens. When i press the button and the function is called, the arguments of the function are shown on the left panel, but the program freezes, untill i click on "continue". I'd like for it to be in sync, so i could change the value of the "test" on the panel. Maybe is not possible?